# Do we still need deal with the high DPI problem of CANVAS on latest ios or android?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Are there some new solutions for the blurry image drawing of html5 canvas on high DPI device? Except the "classic" devicePixelRatio and canvas enlarging.